# UILabel - Equal Truncation

Tags: swift, uilabel

I want to create a truncating label that looks and works just like the `Section Index Titles List` in a `Table View`. Can this be achieved with a `UILabel` and how?

[image: The Index Titles List.]

Comment: What do you mean by `truncating label`?

Comment: Section index does not truncate anything.

Comment: @PGDev The label adjusts the visible text by removing letters and adding •.

Comment: @matt I edited the question, I was talking about the label visible in the `Table View's` index title list.

Comment: It is not a label. It’s just a view that writes A Bullet D Bullet etc in a vertical column.

Comment: Are you asking how to do the same thing in your own table view?

Comment: @matt No, I want a label or similar that displays A bullet D bullet etc. in a similar way, depending on the available space. I thought a UILabel would be logical since it already contains truncating possibilities.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195116/discussion-between-evenwerk-and-matt).

Comment: But I told you the table view index does not truncate anything. Its text simply is A, Bullet, and so on. It is showing you it’s entire contents. If you want to write A Bullet D Bullet into a label then just write that.

Comment: @matt I am aware of the built in index titles list in the `UITableView`. I am looking for the dynamic aspect of the list. When there is enough space, the list shows all the items ABCDEF etc. When there isn't enough space the list shows A bullet D bullet etc.

Comment: Then you must write code that sets or changes the text. It isn’t some kind of magic truncation. You must dictate the entire exact contents of the label.

Comment: Ok, I will do that!

Answer (score 1):

To make your table view index look like that one, implement both `sectionIndexTitles` (to dictate the letters and bullets) and `tableView(_:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:at:)` (to set up the correspondence with your actual sections).